# How to arbitrarily enable or disable class method based on specific type?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I have a class like this:

```cpp
struct X
{
    enum Type { INT, FLOAT };
    using val_t = std::tuple<int, float>;

    X(Type t) : type(t) {}

    Type type;

    template<typename T>
    X& operator =(T x)
    {
        // ???
        static_assert(T is the same as `type');

        // ???
        std::get<type>(val) = x;

        return *this;
    }

    val_t val;
};
```

Is it possible to assert at compile time if user tries to assign incompatible value?

For example:

```cpp
X x1(X::INT);
x1 = 5; // OK
x1 = 3.14; // compilation error
```

**Note:** I prefer keeping the class as not a template because I need to keep its instances in collections (like `std::vector` etc).

Comment: if you template the class instead of the method, yes, it is possible to have compile time error.

Comment: `std::is_same` to check if T is float/int/whatever http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same

Comment: @Jarod42, I edited my question to mention that I'd like to keep it as not a template because instances of the class are kept in `std::vector`.

Comment: `X x1(rand() ? X::INT : X::FLOAT);` `x1 = 5.2;` - ok or error?

Comment: @Raxvan, would you be able to provide a code example? Thanks.

Comment: @deniss, I have the benefit of knowing X's type at compile time. That's why I believe I can do this with some `constexpr` trick or similar.

Comment: @Alex Blekhman updated post

Comment: `X x1(X::INT), x2(X::FLOAT); X* x = rand() ? &x1 : &x2; (*x) = 5.2;`. You can't do what you want without encoding type tag into `X` type, through templates like `X<Int>` or manually as `XInt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot: the value of `type_` is run time data, compilation errors are not determined at runtime.

You could do:

```
enum Type { INT, FLOAT };
template<Type type_>
struct X {
  using val_t = std::tuple<int, float>;


  template<typename T>
  X& operator =(T x) {
    // ???
    static_assert((type_==INT&&std::is_same<T,int>{})||(type_==FLOAT&&std::is_same<T,float>{}),
      "types do not match"
    );
    std::get<T>(val) = x;

    return *this;
  }

  val_t val;
};
X<INT> x1;
x1 = 5; // OK
x1 = 3.14; // compilation error
```

but I do not see much point.

One way would be to have a base type that does not do the checking just stores state, and a derived that knows its type.

```
struct Base{
  enum {INT,FLOAT} Type;
  // etc
};
template<Base::Type type>
struct Derived:private Base{
  Derived():Base(type){}
  using Base::some_method; // expose base methods
  Base& get_base()&{return *this;}
  Base get_base()&&{return std::move(*this);}
  Base const& get_base()const&{return *this;}

  template<class T>
  Derived& operator=( T o){
    static_assert((type_==INT&&std::is_same<T,int>{})||(type_==FLOAT&&std::is_same<T,float>{}),
      "types do not match"
    );
    Base::operator=(std::move(o));
    return *this;
  }
};
```

`Base` does not check, at best it runtime asserts.  `Derived` checks at compile time.

Niw when you know the type statically at compile time you use `Derived<INT> d;`; when you do not, or need to forget, use `.get_base()` or a `Base b(type_enum_val);`.

Comment: I believe there is a chance to achieve it because X's type can be known at compile time. I tried to use `constexpr`, but couldn't find any working solution.

Comment: @AlexBlekhman: X's type is X. That is how the C++ type system works. If `constexpr` would work, then `template` would work. Behind the scenes, they're closely related. The problem is that you can't make a choice. Either `X<int>` is a different type than `X<float>`, or there's a single `X` type.

Comment: @alex There is such a "chance", but it involves template non-type arguments and not constructor arguments.  Barring a coq-like precondition postcondition system with automated theorem checking and the ability to pass said proofs to argument calls you are not getting compile time asserts on data **you** have told the compiler can vary at runtime. The data that does not "vary at runtime" for an instance of a variable in C++ is encoded in its **type**.  We can have an expression fail to be constexpr based on "runtime" (well, run at compile time) state, but that is not what you asked.

Comment: I mean in C++17 I could turn the type of a ctor argument into type data in the instance, but that is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Yakk, I see your point. Agree, seems to be impossible at this stage of C++. I wish they added some sort of basic reflection to the language.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have `Type type;` you can't assert at compiletime if `type` is INT or FLOAT or whatever you have. For that check you can only assert at runtime.

For everything else you can do a compiletime check, and a runtime check for using some template meta-programming:

```
namespace detail_tuple
{
    template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename... ARGS>
    struct get_by_type_impl {
        enum {
            kIdx = N
        };
    };
    template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename... ARGS>
    struct get_by_type_impl<T, N, T, ARGS...> {
        enum {
            kIdx = N
        };
    };
    template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename U, typename... ARGS>
    struct get_by_type_impl<T, N, U, ARGS...> {
        enum {
            kIdx = get_by_type_impl<T, N + 1, ARGS...>::kIdx
        };
    };
}
template <typename, typename>
struct validator;
template <typename T, typename... ARGS>
struct validator < T, std::tuple<ARGS...> >
{
    static void validate(const std::size_t type_idx)
    {
        //compiletime checks
        //get index of type T in ARGS...
        constexpr auto ind = detail_tuple::get_by_type_impl<T, 0, ARGS...>::kIdx;
        //check if index is valid
        static_assert(ind < sizeof...(ARGS), "Type index out of bounds, type T is was not found in the tuple!");

        //runtime checks
        if (type_idx != ind)
            std::cout << "Incompatible type index!\n";
    }
};

struct X
{
    enum Type
    {
        INT = 0,
        FLOAT,
        TYPE_COUNT,
    };
    using val_t = std::tuple<int, float>;


    X(Type t) : type(t) {}

    Type type;

    template<typename T>
    X& operator =(const T& x)
    {
        validator<T, val_t>::validate(type);

        std::get<T>(val) = x;
        return *this;
    }

    val_t val;
};
```

for that `std::get` uses type T instead of `type`

Comment: Note that this disables SFINAE checks. If you have a generic type and you want to see whether `foo = bar` works, you now have a hard error instead of a no answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this won't work. `static_assert` should check against specific type that was used to construct X. I provided example where assignment to a different type results in compilation error. In your example I can assign both `int` and `float` values without compilation errors.